# PHP SOAP request script getting 500 error on LAMP server

Tags: php, soap, wamp, lamp

I have a PHP script that sends a SOAP request to an ASMX API that is owned by a dfferent division of the company that I work for.  I developed this script in the WAMP environment on my personal company PC and it works fine in that environment, successfully recveiving and parsing the response.  However when I upload this script to the LAMP-based development server (which was just setup) and attempt to run it through a web browser, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. The web engineer who setup the server says he installed and enabled the PHP SOAP extension. Does anybody know of anything else used in the code below that needs to be activated on the server that would cause a 500 error by its absence?

Here is the code that sends the request, minus the actual XML body, which is being processed correctly by the API.  The code following this snippet simply pulls various values out of the arrays that are returned and echoes them out.

```
//Common SOAP client options that can be set.  
$clientOptions = array(
    'exceptions'=>true, 
    'trace'=>1, 
    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'location' => $endpointURL);

//The creation of the client object. We pass it a reference to the WSDL.    
$requestXML = '<GetRateQuote xmlns="<URL>">
    CORRECTLY FORMATTED XML IS HERE
</GetRateQuote>';
$requestObj = new SoapVar($requestXML,XSD_ANYXML);
$client = new SoapClient($endpointURL . "?wsdl", $clientOptions);

    //Retrieve the response.
    $result = $client->GetRateQuote($requestObj);

    //Put the data into a variable to be parsed
    $data = $result->GetRateQuoteResult;....
```

Comment: Is there a message in the 500 error? If not, check the error log and see if it's writing anything while processing the request.

Comment: Might want to check out HEREDOC for your XML.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I checked the logs that I could find when I first got the 500 error Monday and could not see any useful messages.  But after seeing your response yesterday, I checked them again and found a bunch of "class SoapVar not found" messages, which suggest SOAP was not enabled.  Next I looked at phpinfo and there was no SOAP section at all, which also suggests that as I had suspected all along SOAP was not installed or enabled.

Comment: Our web engineer just confirmed that the PHP SOAP extension was not activated before because the Apache service was not restarted after they changed the settings.  He restarted it and the SOAP request is now working.